# Stop auto creating invoice for authorized.net cim payment method -M2

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, authorize.net

I want to capture order payment but do not want to create invoice.

How can we achieve this?

I found this file:
**vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment/Operations/CaptureOperation.php**

Any help will be appriciated.

[image]

[image]